# Find the integers $x, y, z$ such that $\sqrt{x...x - y...y} = z...z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an exercise as follows: ''Find all of the integers $x,y,z \in \{1,2,\ldots , 9\}$ such that $$\sqrt{\underset{2n \mbox{ times } x}{\overline{ x\ldots x}} - \underset{n \mbox{ times } y}{\overline{y \ldots y}}} = \underset{n \mbox{ times } z}{ \overline{z \ldots z}}$$ with $2$ natural numbers $n$.''

For example, $x= 1; y =2; z= 3$ is a solution of this exercise because $$\sqrt{11 - 2} = 3  
 \ (\mbox{with } n=1)$$ and $$\sqrt{1111 - 22} = \sqrt{1089} = 33\  (\mbox{with }n = 2).$$

I know that $y $ must to be even. However, I can't give a full solution. I hope seeing some your hints for this problem.

Thank you so much for all your comments.

Best wishes,

Comment: This is equivalent to finding $x,y,z$ such that $x^{2n}-y^n=z^{2n}$.

Comment: @Nicolas, it looks like OP means numbers written in decimal using a single digit $n$ or $2n$ times, not  numbers raised to a power $n$ or $2n$.

Comment: Is $x=2,y=6,z=4$ a solution when $n=1$? Or is the equation mean to hold for all natural numbers $n$?

Comment: There's also $x=4$, $y=8$, $z=6$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I misunderstood the notation, thank you for your message!

Comment: @SeeHai This equation must to be holds for two natural numbers n.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you so much! However, as the comment of GerryMyerson, this notation means numbers written in decimal using a single digit (in here, x) n times.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you so much! So I need to repair my question now!

Answer (score 3):

The given equation is the same as
$$\frac{10^{2n}-1}{9}x - \frac{10^n-1}{9}y = \left(\frac{10^n-1}{9}z\right)^2,$$
or
$$\tag{*}(10^n+1)x - y = \frac{10^n-1}{9}z^2.$$
Since a solution is required for two different $n$, suppose that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution for both $n$ and $m$. Subtracting $(*)$ for $m$ from $(*)$ for $n$, we get
$$(10^n-10^m)x = \frac{10^n-10^m}{9}z^2,$$
or $z^2 = 9x$. This forces $(x,z) = (1,3)$, $(4,6)$, or $(9,9)$. But $x=z=9$ implies $(10^n+1)\cdot 9 - y = (10^n-1)\cdot 9$, or $y=18$, which is impossible. Thus $(x,y,z) = (1,2,3)$ or $(4,8,6)$ are the only solutions.

Note that each of these is a solution for any $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your  solution and your hints! They are so nice! I will rethink about them!

Comment: Yes, (7,3,8) is a solution with n=2. However, there also must to exist  another natural number n (not 2) such that (7,3,8) be also a solution!

Comment: I missed that condition.

Comment: Thank a lot for your update. Your equation (*) is really the best key!